# Postgres percentile_cont with cardinality

Tags: postgresql, percentile

I have been using the new percentile_cont in Postgres to calculate percentiles for a table ever since it was launched. However, we are now changing the table to include cardinality for each row, and I'm unsure as to how to implement percentile_cont to take this into account.

Let's say the table looked like this before:

```
+--------+--------------+
| name   | age          |
+--------+--------------+
|  Joe   | 10           |
+--------+--------------+
|  Bob   | 11           |
+--------+--------------+
|  Lisa  | 12           |
+--------+--------------+
```

Calculating the 85th percentile for age in the set would simply be done using: `percentile_cont(0.85) WITHIN group (ORDER BY age asc) 85`

Now, we have a cardinality for each name (the number of people with that specific name). It looks something like this:

```
+--------------+--------+
| name   | age | count  |
+--------+-----+--------+
|  Joe   | 10  |   2    |
+--------+-----+--------+
|  Bob   | 11  |   1    |
+--------+-----+--------+
|  Lisa  | 12  |   1    |
+--------+-----+--------+
```

Is there any way to use percentile_cont or any other built in function in Postgres to calculate the percentile taking the count/cardinality into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to duplicate rows according to `count`.

The first thing I thought of was a recursive query:

```
with recursive data (name, age, count) as (
    select * 
    from a_table
union all
    select name, age, count- 1
    from data
    where count > 1
    )
select name, age 
from data
order by name, age;
```

In Postgres, you can use [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to get the same in an easier and faster way.

```
select name, age
from a_table
cross join generate_series(1, count)
order by name, age;
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1aa08f2c7a6b3300a7cc8b7ee198049f)

Comment: No lateral join with `generate_series(count)`?